# Stripe retrieve all the paid amount on a subscription

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a subscription with proration. So for the first months, the client is charged 10 euros and for the last month the client is charged 9.99. Sometimes, some coupons are applied and the client is charged 5 euros. How can I  get the total of all the amounts paid by this customer for this subscription? I need to get the sum of 10 x (number of months) + 9.99 + 5 x (number of months where coupons was applied).. In other words, I need to get all the amount of all the money he previously paid until now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve all the invoices for a given `Customer` https://stripe.com/docs/api/invoices/list. If you want the invoices for a particular `Subscription`, pass in the `subscription` parameter.

You can then iterate through all the invoices and sum the amounts paid. Note that you can only retrieve up to 100 invoices.

Comment: Thanks !! I read  from an OLD post that stripe won't return more than 100 invoices, and we have to use offset or something like this .. is that still true? and if so how to do it? it's important for me to retrieve ALL the invoices .

Comment: You're right. That limitation still applies. By default it retrieves 10 invoices, the max is 100. So ideally this is something you might want to store in your database, if you want to offer your users the ability to view all invoices, in the event your user exceeds the limit.

Comment: If I looped over the entire number of invvoices and i want to get the amount of each one, should I get this amount from the payment intent  just like you told me to do in one of the previous posts "The Invoice object contains the `payment_intent field. This is likely what you're looking for." or should I just use amount_paid or charge-> amount or charge->amount_captured or invoice->total ?  I wanna make sure that I getting a value that the user has really paid .

Comment: Just retrieve the `total` value from the `Invoice` will do. This is the amount that the user paid after discounts, if applicable, has been applied.